# Query in MongoDb for fetching record

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongoDb for saving my object.

This is my payloadObject :

```
   {
  "_id" : ObjectId("53763e6fe4b00e612650c18c"),
  "_class" : "mkcl.os.transformer.PayloadObject",
  "formId" : NumberLong(22),
  "dataMap" : {
    "gpsLocation" : "Latitude: 18.6099243, Longitude:73.7710601,Altitude:0.0",
    "85" : "Prahlad Singh",
    "86" : "25",
    "88" : "16/05/14",
    "92" : "",
    "89" : "Male",
    "91" : "Single",
    "87" : "Pune",
    "90" : "Employement"
  },
  "imageUrls" : { }
    }
```

There are such 100 records, Now I wants to fetch records having key 90 . So that I get value of fields 90 (Like Employment in this case)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $exists clause:

```
db.<coll>.find({"dataMap.90": {$exists: true}}, {"dataMap.90": 1})
```

Comment: the name of the field is "dataMap.90"